# How does one get widget values with a button in ipython

Tags: widget, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a function createWidgets whose purpose is to take a list of strings and create a list of containers for each string -> 1 container = a textbox and checkbox.  Each container is then put into a large container.

What I am trying to do is append a button to the container that on_click takes all the "True"s and puts all the modified strings and puts them in a dataframe

```
    widgelist = e.options
    txtBox_type = 'text_widget' # Define if Area box o regular txtbox
    bigContainer = createWidgets(widgelist, txtBox_type)

    Function
    def createWidgets(widgelist, txtBox_type):

        #containerList = []
        i = 0

        for k in widgelist:
        ## Build Container widgets

           chBox_Widget = widgets.CheckboxWidget(description = str(i),value = False,)
           if txtBox_type == 'textA_widget': # Check wether txtBox should be an area txt box or not.
               txt_Widget = widgets.TextareaWidget( description = str(i), value = k)
           else:
               txt_Widget = widgets.TextWidget( description = str(i), value = k)

        container = widgets.ContainerWidget()
        container.children = [chBox_Widget, txt_Widget]
        containerList.append(container)

        i+= 1

        button = widgets.ButtonWidget(description = 'Add')
        bigContainer = widgets.ContainerWidget()
        bigContainer.children = containerList

        return  bigContainer
```

I have gone to many websites and spent many days on this help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As near as I can interpret the question, the code below should provide an answer:

```py
import IPython.html.widgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Thing'])

def createWidgets(widgelist):

    ## Each CheckboxWidget and TextWidget are enclosed in a subwidget.  We use a 
    ## list comprehension to construct a list of these subwidgets.
    containerList = [
        widgets.ContainerWidget(children=(widgets.CheckboxWidget(description=k)
                                          widgets.TextWidget(value=k)))
        for k in widgelist]
    bigContainer = widgets.ContainerWidget(children=containerList)

    ## To arrange the CheckboxWidget in a row with the TextWidget, we have to
    ## first display them, then remove_class('vbox') and add_class('hbox'). This 
    ## bit of awkwardness in the IPython version 2.x notebook will hopefully 
    ## be fixed in version 3.x.  Displaying bigContainer also displays it's children.
    display(bigContainer)
    for c in containerList:
        c.remove_class('vbox')
        c.add_class('hbox')

    return  bigContainer

widgelist = ['ThingA', 'ThingB', 'ThingC', 'ThingD']
bigContainer = createWidgets(widgelist, txtBox_type)

## Callback for button.on_click.
def add_to_dataframe(a):
    # The children of bigContainer are also containers,
    # each with first child a CheckboxWidget and second
    # child a TextWidget.  We iterate through them and
    # if checked, add the text to the dataframe df as
    # an additional row.
    for c in bigContainer.children:
        if c.children[0].value:
            df.loc[len(df)+1] = (c.children[1].value,)
            display(df)

    clear_output()
    display(df)

button = widgets.ButtonWidget(description = 'Add')
button.on_click(add_to_dataframe)

display(button)
```

Here is a screen clip of the widget area and output after adding a few rows to the dataframe.

[image: Here is a screen clip of the widget area and output after adding a few rows to the dataframe.]

I would have designed the code to do this somewhat differently, but I tried to stay
close to your code organization.

Comment: Yes it does and more! Adding checkbox was a real bonus.  I settled for much less.  I guess the part **I do not understand** is how does the `Callback for button.on_click.` inherit `bigContainer`?

Comment: Yes, that could be confusing.  Inside the callback function `add_to_dataframe(...)` the variable `bigContainer` is actually a global variable - you can see it defined three lines above.  But inside the function `createWidgets(...)` there is also a local variable definition of `bigContainer`.  A search for "python variable scope" lead me to [this explanation](http://gettingstartedwithpython.blogspot.com/2012/05/variable-scope.html) but you will find many more expositions of of this.

Answer (score 0):

This is updated version for Ipython3 on jupyternotebooks 4

Just rename:

- widgets.ContainerWidget ->widgets.Box
- widgets.CheckboxWidget -> widgets.Checkbox
- widgets.TextWidget     -> widgets.Text

Reference: [https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/whatsnew/version3_widget_migration.html]